# jquery: position?

Tags: jquery, position

I am trying to use [jquery Position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position#options) to position an element relative to another.

Basically the trigger element is 15px * 15px.

The target element is 200px*200px

I want to have,

when I click the trigger element,
have the target element positioned so the top of it matches the top of the trigger,

and have the left of the target element be 5px from the right of the trigger element.

How should I do this?

(note: $('#target'), $('#trigger');)

Comment: please post your code, it'll make it easier to answer you

Comment: This depends on the positioning scheme (relative, absolute, static) of both elements and their respective parent elements. Pleaes post the html for the document you are using.

Comment: i updated my answer, check if you want something on that lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [offset](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position#option-offset) in [jQuery UI Position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position) (as you say you are trying to use), like this:

```
$("#trigger").click(function() {
    $("#target").position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "right top",
      of: "#trigger",
      offset: "5 0"
    });
});
```

Comment: for some reason doing this it is being positioned at the top of the document, with the left hand side of the target matching the left hand side of the trigger...

Comment: @Haliwood: as i mentioned in my comment on your question - the origin used to calculate position depends on the position scheme of both the element being positioned and its ancestors... without this information we cant really give you a solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

jquery offset has top and left property's you can use them

```
http://api.jquery.com/offset/
```

get the trigger elements offset ,

```
var triggerPostion=$('#triggerPostion').offset();

var targetLeft=triggerPostion.left// manipulate the values
var targetTop=triggerPostion.top

$('#targetDivID').css('position','absolute');
$('#targetDivID').css('top',targetLeft);
$('#targetDivID').css('left',targetTop);
```

Comment: give that object position as absolute , so that left and top will work

Comment: This will work, but he is trying to use jQuery UI Position, right?

Comment: @peter i don't know we have plugin like this , sorry i overlooked it.

Comment: It was released in jQuery UI 1.8. It's really nice and easy way to get cross browser support for some annoying positioning issues, but it might be overkill sometimes.